# Evento click jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, eventos, click

Soy nueva en esta o comunidad. Necesito ayudaaa!! Estoy perdida con los eventos de jQuery y necesito el evento (click) para que me funcione mi código. 
Necesito que me saque la puntuación al pulsar en la estrella. ¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

```
<script>
    function agrandar() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "300px",
            height: "300px",
        })
    }

    function disminuir() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "90px",
            height: "90px",
        })

    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").hover(agrandar, disminuir);
    });

    //Opacidad. Creo que se hace asi, pero me falta algo para que se queden opacas las estrellas no selecionadas..
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").fadeTo(1000, 0.4);

    });
    //Evento click


</script>
<style>
    .estrella1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

</style>
```

En el body tengo las 5 imágenes de las estrellas, no me deja incluir el código.

Comment: Bienvenida a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio, ademas asi obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). No intentes agregar todo el HTML, basta que agregues la sección donde se ven las "estrellas". No veo tu evento `click`

Comment: Hola @Rebeca, puedes añadir el HTML que falta?? Gracias!!

Comment: No se como se añade, jejejje. El evento click no está xk no sé hacerlo.

Comment: Para añadir un evento click a un elemento en jquery solo tienes que seleccionar las estrellas y añadir el click con la función correspondiente:
$('.estrella1').click(function(){ //code })
Supong que esta clase es común a todas las estrellas.

Answer (score 0):

Te adjunto una pregunta similar que hice hará un tiempo con una solución en jQuery. 
[Valoracion estrellas [1-5] Diseño estrellas PHP HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126046/valoracion-estrellas-1-5-dise%C3%B1o-estrellas-php-html)

Comment: ese es php, no me sirve.